# AVSpeechSynthesizer and IOS Text-To-Speech Pronunciation differences

Tags: ios, avfoundation, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

Using AVSpeechsynthesizer with the en-us voice. For some reason words like "a" will be pronounced "ah" in my app but when I use the voiceover "speak" button within an iphone app (text messaging for example) it will pronounce "a" as in "aye". Other small differences include the AVSpeechsynthesizer pronouncing "A" as "Capital A" and the speak button pronouncing "A" as "Aye".

Anyone have any insight as to why the sythesizers pronounce differently?
Ideally I would like the TTS I use to pronounce things the same exact way as the iOS voiceover.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for the 'Capital A' problem ?

Comment: You can find an answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519154/avspeechsynthesizer-text-to-speech

Comment: I ended up having to add a mini markup parser that allowed for an explicit pronunciation and default explicit pronunciations.