# AVSpeechSynthesizer Text-To-Speech

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

AVSpeechsynthesizer with the en-us voice is pronunciation for "A" is "Capital A" but Just want "A" How can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only happens when there is single character in the string,

you can use this workaround of checking if lenght of string is 1 than convert it to lowercase string,

```
NSString *stringToUtter = @"A";
if (stringToUtter.length==1) {
    stringToUtter = [stringToUtter lowercaseString];
}
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:stringToUtter];
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMinimumSpeechRate;
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-us"];
[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Answer (score 0):

The perfect pronunciation can be obtained thanks to the **IPA notation** *(International Phonetic Alphabet)*, no need of workaround.  :o)

Put an `attributedString` with its appropriate attribute as incoming parameter of the `AVSpeechUtterance` instance.

To [get the phonemes](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis), I suggest to use the iPhone feature located at `Settings > General > Accessibility > Speech > Pronunciations` *(iOS 12)* ⟹ see this [WWDC 2018 video summary](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#IPA) if you need further details.

Helpful information for the implementation can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56028707/3825084) as well.