# IOS Swift : UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeIPANotation

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

I am trying to make my app to speak in the `IPANotation` using `AVSpeechSynthesizer`, but it not working below is my code snippet,

```
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()

let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello iPhone")
attributedStr.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key(UIAccessibilitySpeechAttributeIPANotation), value: "ˈa͡ɪ.ˈfo͡ʊn", range: NSRange(location: 6, length: 6))

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: attributedString)
synthesizer.speak(utterence)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did my answer provide an appropriate solution for your problem? 

Answer (score 1):

Try the code snippet hereafter *(iOS 12 - Swift 5.0)* :

```
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "hello my little ")

let pronunciationKey = NSAttributedString.Key(rawValue: AVSpeechSynthesisIPANotationAttribute)
let attrStr2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "blablabla",
                                         attributes: [pronunciationKey: "ˈa͡ɪ.ˈfo͡ʊn"])

let finalAttrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
finalAttrStr.append(attrStr)
finalAttrStr.append(attrStr2)

let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(attributedString: finalAttrStr)
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")

let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
synthesizer.speak(utterance)
```

This is not perfect but it **makes the IPA notation work using [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18236.html#wwdc-2018-making-ios-talk-with-avspeechsynthesizer)**.

Another [example](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#speech-synthesis) is also available to figure out how to get the phonemes and put them into the code.